# Running Sonar Ant Task under Webspahere Application Server 8.5

Tags: jpa, websphere, sonarqube

## Backgroud

We have a Java Entreprise Application running in WAS8. This application needs to run a SonarQube AntTask to analyze some classes.

## Problem

When executing the Ant task, SonarQube initialize Hibernate. Here is the SystemOut log:

```
INFO  - Load batch settings
INFO  - User cache: /home/SVCEsDev0066/.sonar/cache
INFO  - Install plugins
INFO  - Install JDBC driver
INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://180.101.185.60:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
```

After that we've this error message:

```
 org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:229)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
 at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
 at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
 at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:53)
 at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:48)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor152.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
 at org.sgb.builder.jobs.BuilderJob.checkoutAndBuild(BuilderJob.java:277)
 at org.sgb.builder.jobs.BuilderJob.execute(BuilderJob.java:90)
 at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
 at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
 Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.findAllProviders(Persistence.java:93)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:49)
 at org.sonar.jpa.session.AbstractDatabaseConnector.createEntityManagerFactory(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:66)
 at org.sonar.jpa.session.AbstractDatabaseConnector.start(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:46)
 at org.sonar.jpa.session.DefaultDatabaseConnector.start(DefaultDatabaseConnector.java:37)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
 at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
 at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
 at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
 at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
 at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
 at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
 at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
 at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
 at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
 at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
 at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
 at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
 at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
 at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
 ... 22 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:599)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:743)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:720)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.findAllProviders(Persistence.java:79)
 ... 49 more
```

Sonar is trying to load the class: **com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl** which is provider by the Application Server JPA configuration. We've tried to change the provider from WAS  Console to use OpenJPA, but nothing changed: it tries to load the same class once again.

## Question/s

Is there anyway to force Sonar to not use this provider?
An alternative could be to force Sonar to load  com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl class but, where can we find it? and, how can we force it?

## More Details

We've started using SonarQube 4.3.2 and after first error we updated it to 4.5.1. The SonarAntTask version is 2.2. This is our AntTask code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="sonar" name="SonarAnt">
<target name="sonar">
  <taskdef resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" classpath="sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar"/>
    <sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant"/>
</target>
<property name="sonar.java.source" value="1.7"/>
<property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="build_2"/>
<property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="******"/>
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://***.***.***.***:9000"/>
<property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="******"/>
<property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://***.***.***.***:3600/sonar?  useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="PortalSGS_V01R00F00"/>
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="PortalSGS Desc"/>
<property name="sonar.modules" value="sgs-business-review"/>
<property name="sgs-business-review.sonar.projectName" value="sgs-business-review"/>
<property name="sgs-business-review.sonar.projectBaseDir" value="C:\ARQDISP\tmp\CreavistaBL_xIS10460_20140806_110225\vSGS_Portal\SGS_Business_ALM\sgs-business-review"/>
<property name="sgs-business-review.sonar.sources" value="src"/>
```

We've also tried to specify a classpath in te ant task definition like this:

```
  <target name="sonar">
<taskdef resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" classpath="sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar"/>
<sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant"/>
```

But nothing happened.

## Invocating ant task

This is the way our application invokes the task:

1.- Creates an antTask.xml like the showed

2.- Initializes an org.apache.tools.ant.Project object and an org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper

3.-It calls executeTarget method from Project class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to tell us which version of SonarQube and the Ant task you are using? Also, can you copy-paste a snippet of your build.xml file to see how you declare the "sonar" task? Looks like the "sonar" task is not executed on its own classpath.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice, I've have update the question with the versions and a snippet of our antTask file.

Comment: SonarQube Runner is executed in an isolated classloader where classes of the parent classloader are not visible. So it is expected that com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl can't be seen. The problem here is why did it try to load this class? It should means META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is not properly filtered. But I was not able to reproduce. Do you have any custom plugin installed in your SQ instance?

Comment: We've a standar installation with java, javascprit and web plugins. 
I think websphere classloader is messing around with sonar classes. 
I've updated the question including the way we execute ant task.